# Does SQL Server 2017 Express support Linked Server connections to Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2017, linked-server, license

Is there any restrictions with "Linked Servers" with SQL Server 2017 Express?  Vs using SQL Server 2017 Standard.   Only in regards to "Linked Servers".

Comment: Do you have a problem defining one? What does documentation say?

Comment: the documentation does not mention any restrictions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: It works tested with Oracle 19c

Comment: I know SQL Server "Standard" license works with Linked Server connections.   Wondering about "Express"?  I found some google hits saying Express didnt work well with Linked Server connections but upon looking at Article it was SQL Server Express 2012 - long ago.